# jq: error Cannot index string with string. How to parse json file with variable object values using jq

Tags: arrays, json, parsing, object, jq

I have a json file that looks like:

```
[
{"start": "xxx", "final": {"name": "uuu", "content": "{'Date': 'Thu, 07 Mar 2019', 'Type': 'text'}"}},
{"start": "yyy", "final": {"name": "nnn", "content": "{'Date': 'Thu, 07 Mar 2019'}"}}
]
```

The `"final"` holds an object which contains two keys: `name` and `content`. The `content` value is an object. It may be empty, and it may contains different keys.

However, I am interested in certain keys if appeared in the `content`. In this example, if "Type" is included, I want to parse it. If not, just insert "not found".

When I run this `jq` command, I get this error:

```
jq: error (at <stdin>:4): Cannot index string with string "Type"
```

This is because the second object in my json file does not contain `Type`.

Is there a solution to this problem?

```
cat test.json | jq -r '.[] | "\(.start),\(.final["name"]),\(.final["content"]["Type"])"'
jq: error (at <stdin>:4): Cannot index string with string "Type"
```

Comment: The value of the "content" field is a JSON string that looks like the stringified version of a JSON object but cannot be converted to a JSON object using jq's builtin 'fromjson' filter. Would it be acceptable to change the value of the content field so that it is either valid JSON or amenable to conversion to JSON using `fromjson`?

Comment: `Would it be acceptable to change the value of the content field so that it is either valid JSON or amenable to conversion to JSON using fromjson`. I read the `content` object from another source. I use `python` to build my final `json` file that I use `jq` to parse it. I do not mind to convert the `content` object to a `json` object if this will not alter its content at all. How to do this? I read it as a string with '`{` and `}`

Comment: It looks like you could simply use escaped double-quotes instead of single-quotes, or better yet, use python to output valid JSON.  If you don't know how, please consider asking a separate SO question focused on python usage.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since the value of the "content" field cannot be processed directly by `fromjson`, the following solution first translates the single-quotes to escaped double-quotes, and then applies your filter:

```
map(.final.content |= (gsub("'";"\"") | fromjson))
| .[]
| "\(.start),\(.final["name"]),\(.final["content"]["Type"])"
```

Output using the -r command-line option:

```
xxx,uuu,text
yyy,nnn,null
```

### CSV

If you want valid CSV output, it would probably be better to use the `@csv` filter:

```
.[]
| .final.content |= (gsub("'";"\"") | fromjson)
| [.start, .final["name"], .final["content"]["Type"]]
| @csv
```

### Invocation

With the jq program in a file, say program.jq, the appropriate invocation would look like this:

```
jq -r -f program.jq test.json
```

### Variation

If you want to handle missing values specially, you could use `//` e.g as follows:

```
(.final["content"]["Type"] // "NA")
```

### Handling embedded double-quotes

```
.final.content |= (gsub("\"";"\\\"") | gsub("'";"\"") | fromjson)
```

Comment: Can you please write the full command? I tried yours with prefix `cat test.json | ` but it gives error: bash: syntax error near unexpected token .final.content
`

Comment: Thanks. How to write a string instead of `null` if the `Type` value in the `content` object is not found?

Comment: I tried your solution in larger files. It failed to handle this object.  `{"start": "yyy", "final": {"name": "nnn", "content":"{'PP':'CP=\"This is not a policy! See ... for more info.\"'}"}}`. It gives this error: jq: error (at test.json:4): Invalid numeric literal

Comment: Indeed, translating single-quotes to double-quotes is at best a band-aid. You could try applying additional band-aids, or better yet, fix the problem at the source.

Comment: I want to read raw data as-is. I do not control how it is written as I collect it from the web. Then parse it. But the data is tricky. Any suggestions?